# Convert simple xml to soap?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have some code that converts an `object` to an xml string using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`, then http posts it to a URL which worked great.

It seems the server has now upgraded to SOAP-XML.

Is there a way I can serialize my object into SOAP-XML?
I planned to use `SoapFormatter`, but this appears to be deprecated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following namespace

**Namespace**:  `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap`

**Assembly**:  `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap (in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll)`

NOTE: remember to add a reference to the assembly showed above

for more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Ive just tried it and all the hierarchy has disappeared, plus it has added a lot of other elements in ('transactionIdentifierField', 'transactionStatusCodeField'...)

Comment: i.e. should look like: http://ota-tools.sourceforge.net/ota-soapui/images/06-send2.jpg